# Does it make sense to create wrapper classes for another library, purely so the end user doesn't have to install/import that library?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, api-design

In this specific case I'm using C# and Emgu, where I made a wrapper around the `Capture()` object, purely so that the end user of the library that I made doesn't have to put using Emgu` in their client code.

My wrapper adds no functionality, and I've been debating whether it should even be it's own thing or if I should just put it into one of the other classes. The reason I'm considering this at all is that a key requirement is that the installation process should be as light weight as possible.

I couldn't find anything in the MSDN user guide.

Comment: Is simplicity and decoupling what you are looking for with wrapping?

Answer (score 7):

Creating wrappers around third-party libraries is not a terrible idea, though maybe not for the reasons you're wanting. Consider a point in the future when you want to switch which image processing library you use, or even write your own implementation. With proper interfaces, your client code doesn't change at all - only the implementation does. Your implementation changes from calling Emgu to calling NewLibrary or to calling your own code.

If you're using dependency injection, you'll need a small change to point it to the new implementation, but that would allow you to keep both implementations, and switch between them as needed.

Comment: +1. Also it depends who the OP wants to be in control of the image processing library. Should clients be able to bring whichever one they want, or is OP's library coupled to Emgu?

Comment: It's also worth considering encapsulation. Many libraries expose a lot of functionality that your particular application may not use. It's a good idea to only expose the functionality you are using.